# How to Get All Custom Category Attribute Values?

Tags: category, eav

I have created module that add custom attribute in Manage Categories section. Say My custom category attribute is `category_sku`, and it is a text field.

I see that the value of my custom attribute is stored in `catalog_category_entity_text` table.

But how to populate all the values of it?

I tried using the below code, but it return NULL.

```
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_category', 'category_sku')->getValue();
```

Comment: Your wording seems ambiguous. Are you trying to ask how you can provide a list of options to choose from whenever you want to set this value?

Comment: Yes, I want to provide an option list with the values of my custom attribute. But I'm getting stuck trying to populate the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing it in phtml file like this way

```
<?php $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*'); ?>

<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
   <?php $categorySku = $category->getCategory_sku(); ?>
   <?php print_r ($categorySku); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

That way I can populate all my custom category attribute values which is `category_sku` :).

And this will make it to a select option list.

```
    <?php $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*'); ?>

        <select id="my-id" name="my-name">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
<?php /*magento fetch data by using get and attibute name like banner_id change to getBannerId*/   ?>
                <?php $categorySku = $category->getCategorySku(); ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $categorySku; ?>"><?php echo $categorySku; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to the something very similar to this but I can't get it to work. 
I hope get some answers from the wise guys out her.

I need to get a attribute collection of the current category for example. 
I have 4 custom attributes (images) that I would like to use for category slider

```
<?php $category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
      $categories =$category->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect(array('sliderimg1','sliderimg2','sliderimg3','sliderimg4'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
    ->addAttributeToSort('position', ASC);?>
```

with this code I can get the attributes to show but, how can I add it to my slider?
please help.
I tried

```
 <div id="capabilities" class="detail detail--capabilities">
<div class="gallery" data-flickity='{ "imagesLoaded": true, "wrapAround": true, "autoPlay": 10000}'>
     <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
    <div class="gallery-row gallery-one-column">
        <div class="gallery-item gallery-item--features gallery-item--left">
            <div class="gallery-image"><img class="imgl" style="width:100%; height:100%; object-fit: cover;  object-position: 69% 37%;" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . '/' . 'category' . '/' . $category->getSliderimg1() ?>"></div>
            <div class="gallery-features">
                 <p class="hro1"><i> <?php echo $category->getName() ?></i></p>
                <h1 class="hro"><?php echo $category->getF_title1() ?></h1>
                <!--<p><?php echo $category->getF_desc1() ?><p/>-->
                <div class="hromsrp"><p>MSRP <span><strong><?php echo $category->getMsrp() ?></strong></span></p></div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn1 menu-btn-brp-default" onClick="location.href='<?php echo $category->getUrl(); ?>'">VIEW DETAILS&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

This gets the attribute image for each category...
but I need to create a slider for each category how can I get the other 3 attributes
(sliderimg2,sliderimg3,sliderimg4 ) in to my category slider for the current category only.